# Best Practice: Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

In the [android development tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) on the navigation drawer design pattern the recommended way of managing the different layouts is using fragments. These fragments are swapped through the `FragmentTransaction().replace()` transaction. In my opinion the navigation drawer fragments are usually exchanged and reloaded repeatedly. Therefore wouldn't it make more sense to use the `FragmentTransaction.show()` and `FragmentTransaction.hide()` calls in this context?

What Best Practice for using the `NavigationDrawer` right now?

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are loaded repeatedly, just like activities...

Best practice is what Google expose: `FragmentTransaction.replace()` because:

1. they know what they're doing ^^
2. it keeps only one fragment loaded at a time

Answer (score 1):

If your main concern is about using fragments in Navigation Drawer .. then you can use it.

Fragments just provide a way to easily replace one layout with another without creating a new activity.

If you still want to use activity for your navigation drawer then you can use that.

Now as far as maintaining it's state is concerned then android actionBar in itself provides methods that can maintain your app state.

```
Now as per Android documentation as you are referring .. it is always good to have fragment as they a light weighted in context of to use new activity each time for your app.
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Im fine with using fragments in NavigationDrawer. I just don't understand why the default behaviour of loading these fragments is through .replace() instead of .show() and .hide().

Comment: You must be facing problem of reloading when you get back to your previous activity .. and I hope that you must be using ActionBar.. Is it ?

Comment: I got 5 fragments in my navigation drawer and in each of these fragments i load some json data via a webservice. Now even though i do cache the retrieved data (im using google volley to retrieve data) there is like half a second delay at reloading a fragment, because i have to recreate the fragment first and get the data from the cache, which wouldn't be a problem when keeping the fragment alive in the background with .hide().

Comment: Oh yes .. I am too facing same sort of problem.. Wondering for same. Will let you know ... else please put solution for same if you get. :)